# What does "has been described in other work" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, science

I'm currently reading a book about chemistry. Here is a sentence that I faced and didn't understand:

> This procedure has been described in other work from our laboratory

I don't get what it means by "describe in other work"! The only thing came to my mind was that it was probably "in other words" and it's a misprint or something.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: My guess is that 'work' here means the result of some research, something (a report, a book, a paper, etc.) that was produced by research.

Comment: Such as "a work of art", "the complete works of Shakespeare" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This procedure has been described in other work from our laboratory

Could be paraphrased:

> This way of doing things has been described in other research/papers/books written by the researchers from our laboratory